# ¿Cómo abrir un nuevo cliente sockets en una nueva terminal?

Tags: python, socket

Estoy haciendo un programa cliente-servidor y  mi intención es que al integrarse un nuevo cliente se abra una nueva consola de cmd para ese usuario,

Para lo cual estoy tratando de abrir un script utilizando `subprocess`, este escrip tiene como función recibir y leer los mensajes de su correspondiente usuario.

```
subprocess.call('python nuevoserv.py -{}'.format(cliente), creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Pero no funciona ya que no abre la nueva ventana.

Anexo mis dos códigos:

```
import socket
import threading
from nuevoserv import Nuevo
import os
import subprocess

def Abrir(cliente,direccion):

    subprocess.call('python nuevoserv.py -{}'.format(cliente), creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

servidor = socket.socket()
conexion = ("Angel-Dell",5555)

servidor.bind(conexion)
servidor.listen(5)

while True:
    cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()
    Abrir(cliente,direccion)
```

-

```
import threading
import socket

class Nuevo():
    def __init__(self,cliente):
        self.Cliente = cliente

        self.ListaMensajes = []

        self.ListaAcciones = [
            "Validar"
        ]

    def LeerMensaje(self,cliente):
        while self.ListaMensajes:
            for i,mensaje in enumerate(self.ListaMensajes):
                if mensaje[1] != "cerrar":
                    respuesta = input("> ")
                    mensaje[0].sendall(respuesta.encode())
                    self.ListaMensajes.remove(self.ListaMensajes[i])
                elif mensaje[1] == "cerrar":
                    threading.currentThread()._stop()

    def RecibirMensaje(self):

        while True:
            Mensaje = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
            if Mensaje in self.ListaAcciones:
                self.EjecutarFuncion(Mensaje,self.Cliente,self.Direccion)
            else:
                self.ListaMensajes.append([self.Cliente,Mensaje,self.Direccion])
                if len(self.ListaMensajes) == 1:
                    threading.Thread(target=self.LeerMensaje,args=(self.Cliente)).start()
```

**Actualizacion**

He cambiado el codigo por esta linea:

```
def Abrir(cliente,direccion):
    os.system("start cmd /k python C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/nuevoserv.py {} {}".format(cliente,direccion))
```

sin embargo ahora me arroja un error:

```
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

Comment: Utiliza subprocess.run o subprocess.popen que reemplazan al call.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich, no funciona la venta solo parpadea y se cierra

Comment: usa:  import subprocess from subprocess import Popen p=Popen("Python.exe",executable=None,close_fds=False,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

Comment: Si se abre y cierra la ventana es porque tu programa esta finalizando inmediatamente.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich, delante de `Python.exe` agrefo los argumentos

Comment: si me olvide de añadirlos. Hice una prueba y me funcionó pero solo se queda abierta si el programa no finaliza.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich hare la prueba

Comment: Utilice esto (fijate en la ruta al programa utilizo /): p=Popen("Python.exe   e:/apps/python/list1.py",executable=None,close_fds=False,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

Comment: Prueba con `subprocess.Popen("start python C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/nuevoserv.py {} {}".format(cliente,direccion), shell=True)`.